# Can't Count results from Joined Table mySQL

Tags: mysql

i followed 3 others SO answers, and they say it works.. but here not... here is my problem, i have this QUERY:

```
SELECT
    q.*
FROM relacionamento AS r
INNER JOIN questoes AS q ON r.idquestao = q.id
WHERE tabela = 'disciplina'
GROUP BY q.id
```

This is there result of query:
[image: Query Result]

Until here, it was perfect.. now i need know how much rows returned... i changed the query to this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(q.*)
FROM relacionamento AS r
INNER JOIN questoes AS q ON r.idquestao = q.id
WHERE tabela = 'disciplina'
GROUP BY q.id
```

And got this error:

[image: Error when counting]

Why i cant count how much rows did i get?

**UPDATE:**
I did try do this query also:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM relacionamento AS r
INNER JOIN questoes AS q ON r.idquestao = q.id
WHERE tabela = 'disciplina'
GROUP BY q.id
```

And get this as result:

[image: Count(*)Result]

Comment: Can you post the whole query in which you used `COUNT(q.*)`?

Comment: @user212514 yeah but is the same as the first one.. just changed de second line... 1 second i`ll update with full query

Comment: @user212514, ok, just updated...

Comment: I think you should be specifying the field you want to count, for example, `select count(q.id)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        q.*
    FROM relacionamento AS r
    INNER JOIN questoes AS q ON r.idquestao = q.id
    WHERE tabela = 'disciplina'
    GROUP BY q.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably better written as:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM questoes q
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM relacionamento r
              WHERE r.idquestao = q.id AND r.tabela = 'disciplina'
             );
```

This should be more efficient than your query, if you have an index on `relacionamento(idquestao, tablea)` (which you would want anyway for the `join`).  And, it doesn't use `select *` with `group by`, which just generally looks wrong.

Then, to get the count, you can just do `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM questoes q
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM relacionamento r
              WHERE r.idquestao = q.id AND r.tabela = 'disciplina'
             );
```

Comment: why this query should be more efficient?

Comment: @user1533609 . . . It is not doing an aggregation over the entire data set.